# BizTalkServerIsolatedHost disappeared from one server in multi-server group

Tags: web-services, biztalk

Afternoon all,

We have a group of four BizTalk servers: two orchestration hosts and two adapter hosts. We have a number of orchestrations exposed as web services, and for the purposes of this question, it is important to note that these web services are hosted on the adapter servers, and run under the BizTalkServerIsolatedHost host instance.

This morning, we started seeing odd errors on both of the adapter servers when SOAP calls came into the web services, like this:

> The Messaging Engine failed to
>   register the adapter for “SOAP” for
>   the receive location blahblahblah.
>   Please verify that the receive
>   location exists, and that the isolated
>   adapter runs under an account that has
>   access to the BizTalk databases.

We restarted IIS on both servers, which fixed the errors on ONE server, but the other server continued to fail. The errors continued after a reboot as well.

After chasing our tails for a while, we eventually discovered that the BizTalkServerIsolatedHost host instance on the still-failing server was gone. Just... gone. These applications have been in production for months. Everything had been working swimmingly through the morning, until this just happened.

I don't want to muddy the waters, because I *think* the problems are unrelated, but in the interest of providing enough information, this problem exactly coincided with a problem in our load-balancing network hardware. The load balancer, which provides a single URL to consumers, and round-robins between the two adapter servers, just stopped working. This problem has not been resolved, so I don't know what happened, but it certainly made troubleshooting more interesting...

So, I have two questions:

1. Has anyone seen this before, where a host instance disappears?
2. We cannot find anything in the event viewer or anywhere else that says the host instance was deleted. Is this logged somewhere?

Thanks,
Jason